# Blinking effect when pressing the buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Whenever I press "Get Story" or "Random Story" there's a blinking effect, and I'm not sure what is causing this.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Story Fetcher</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Stories</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="get-container">
                <input type="text" id="story-number" placeholder="Enter story number">
                <button id="get" type="button">Get Story</button>
                <button id="getRandom" type="button">Random Story</button>
            </div>
            <div id="story-container">
                <!-- Story content will be displayed here -->
                <div id="generated-text"></div>
                <button id="clear">Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        header {
            background-color: #ff6600;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 28px;
            margin: 0;
        }

        main {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            min-height: 80vh;
        }

        #content-wrapper {
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            padding: 20px;
            max-width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 20px;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        #story-number {
            padding: 10px 16px;
            font-size: 14px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        #get-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #get, #getRandom, #clear {
            background-color: #ff6600;
            color: #fff;
            border: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 4px;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            outline: none; /* Remove focus outline */
        }

        #story-container {
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            padding: 20px;
            max-width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
        }

        #generated-text {
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 1.5;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            color: #333;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #generated-text span {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        #clear {
            display: block;
            margin: 10px auto;
        }

        @media (min-width: 601px) {
            #content-wrapper {
                max-width: 600px;
                max-height: 40vh;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 600px) {
            #get, #clear {
                font-size: 10px !important;
                padding: 20px 20px !important;
            }
        }
```

**Javascript**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var totalStories = 3;
    var currentStory = null;
    var storyContainer = document.getElementById('story-container');

    function clearStoryContainer() {
        if (storyContainer) {
            storyContainer.style.display = 'none';
            var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
            if (generatedTextElement) {
                generatedTextElement.innerHTML = '';
            }
            var contentWrapper = document.getElementById('content-wrapper');
            if (contentWrapper) {
                contentWrapper.style.marginTop = '0';
            }
            currentStory = null;
        }
    }

    function fetchStory(storyNumber) {
        clearStoryContainer();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'fetch.php?story=' + storyNumber, true);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                if (storyContainer) {
                    storyContainer.style.display = 'block';
                    var generatedText = xhr.responseText;
                    var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
                    if (generatedTextElement) {
                        generatedTextElement.innerHTML = parseAndStyleTitles(generatedText);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Generated text element not found.');
                    }
                    var contentWrapper = document.getElementById('content-wrapper');
                    if (contentWrapper) {
                        contentWrapper.style.marginTop = '60px';
                    } else {
                        console.log('Content wrapper element not found.');
                    }
                    currentStory = storyNumber;
                } else {
                    console.log('Story container element not found.');
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Error fetching story. Status code: ' + xhr.status);
                clearStoryContainer();
                displayErrorMessage('Error fetching story.');
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            console.log('Network error while fetching story.');
            clearStoryContainer();
            displayErrorMessage('Network error while fetching story.');
        };
        xhr.send();
    }

    function displayErrorMessage(errorMessage) {
        if (storyContainer) {
            storyContainer.style.display = 'block';
        }
        var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
        if (generatedTextElement) {
            generatedTextElement.innerHTML = errorMessage;
        }
        var contentWrapper = document.getElementById('content-wrapper');
        if (contentWrapper) {
            contentWrapper.style.marginTop = '60px';
        }
        currentStory = null;
    }

    function parseAndStyleTitles(text) {
        return text.replace(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g, function (match, title) {
            return '<span>' + title + '</span>';
        });
    }

    document.getElementById('get').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var storyNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('story-number').value);

        if (!isNaN(storyNumber) && storyNumber >= 1 && storyNumber <= totalStories) {
            fetchStory(storyNumber);
        } else {
            displayErrorMessage('Please enter a valid number between 1 and ' + totalStories + '.');
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('getRandom').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var randomStoryNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalStories) + 1;
        fetchStory(randomStoryNumber);
    });

    document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function () {
        clearStoryContainer();
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// Read the requested story number from the URL parameter
$storyNumber = $_GET['story'];

// Check if the story number is valid (e.g., within the range of available stories)
$totalStories = 3; // Update this to match the actual total number of stories

if ($storyNumber >= 1 && $storyNumber <= $totalStories) {
    // Read the content of stories.txt
    $storiesFile = file_get_contents('stories.txt');

    // Split the content into stories based on the unique delimiter (<!-- Unique delimiter separating stories -->)
    $stories = preg_split('/<!-- Unique delimiter separating stories -->/', $storiesFile);

    // Get the requested story
    $requestedStory = trim($stories[$storyNumber - 1]); // Adjust the array index

    // Replace newline characters with <br> tags for line breaks
    $formattedStory = nl2br($requestedStory);

    // Return the formatted story as a response
    echo $formattedStory;
} else {
    // Return an error message if the story number is invalid
    echo 'Error: Invalid story number.';
}
?>
```

It would be really nice to have a smooth transition between the stories when pressing the buttons, and not get the blinking effect.

Initially when I press a button it doesn't blink, but when I then press it again it blinks as soon as the button is being clicked on. And it appears like it's the entire div container that blinks, not the entire page.

Would removing `display:none` from the `#story-container` solve this issue?

### Update

I missed the link that ADyson provided, and tried this code out, and it made no difference at all. The blinking effect that I'm experiencing seems to be in the div container, as that's the part that's blinking/flashing for a second. The second link provided with code still cause the same issue.

The issue is still there with the code from the last link that ADyson provided.

I'm not good at describing things, but if I try to describe it this way then. It looks like the buttons "jumps" when I press any of them which might be a better explanation.

So even if I remove the CSS styling completely, the buttons is still appearing like if they're moving around. So I think the issue is in the HTML, JavaScript or in the PHP, but I just don't know where. And it appears that this happens to the 2 buttons as well as the textbox.

When you're testing the code on that website ADyson, you can't actually display a story though, right? It's AFTER the first story has been generated then the buttons and the textbox is starting to behave weird until I refresh the page and press "Random Story" again the first time, then it's starting all over again. I added my code to the website myself, and this is what I get https://jsfiddle.net/u6ymhowd/ It's "Jumping" for me, tried it on 2 screens as well on my phone, and it acts the same everywhere.

Yes, it's indeed immediately after any of the buttons has been pressed, then it's fine until I press any button again. And what happens is that the buttons jumps down to where the title of each story is located to then jump back up to where they should be until I press the button again to display the next story. Regarding the resizing issue, how can I fix this? I don't mind having a horizontal scroll-bar in the container where the story is located.

### Update

That actually worked, but is it possible to make the container smaller in width and have it in the center of the screen but adding a horizontal scroll-bar, without it acting the same way again?

### Update

Yes, I realize now that I said it wrong, I meant a vertical scroll-bar. The idea for this is to make the story container with the buttons and textbox fit in the Streamlabs OBS window when I'm streaming, as I was planning on having a channel point redeem for this.

This seems to have sorted the issues, and it seems like it works really good now. Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: please describe where this "Blinking effect" is seen - it is not clear what you mean as you mention a transition so is this a CSS phenomenon or Javascript?

Comment: The PHP is probably irrelevant so for others to witness the actual affect can you add some of the final rendered HTML (ie:view source and copy from there)

Comment: Have tried to do any debugging to narrow down the issue to something more specific? See also [ask] and how to provide a [mre] of the issue (which I sincerely doubt this large code dump currently is). We're happy to answer clear, specific, focused programming questions. "my code doesn't work, here's the whole shebang, you figure it out", is not really such a question.

Comment: Well, when I press any of the buttons, it kind of looks like the entire div container blinks, which is quite annoying.

Comment: Does this happen before the request is sent, or after the response is parsed?

Comment: Initially when I press a button it doesn't blink, but when I then press it again it blinks as soon as the button is being clicked on.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it, not to the comment section. Also, please check which parts are irrelevant, and remove them

Comment: Inasmuch as this scenario is reproducible without involving PHP (I just used a random public data endpoint instead), I can't see any obvious problem in this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0uarqLfk/ . The main area with the white background resizes according to its contents, but that's all. Is that the "blinking" you mean? It's very hard to work out what a visual glitch _actually_ entails from a one-word description.

Comment: It is likely to do with the css you have applied to the `#story-container` which has an initial `display:none` which is modified in your js code

Comment: `Would removing display:none from the #story-container solve this issue?`....why not try it yourself and find out. But I'd say [probably not](https://jsfiddle.net/0uarqLfk/1/) - assuming the "blinking" is what I referred to above...be great if you could confirm that or not

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0uarqLfk/2/) any better??

Comment: `and tried this code out`...if you mean the _first_ link I provided, that was supposed to be an attempt to demo the issue, as I thought I'd made clear. Certainly not a solution, yet. The second version is suggesting that the display:none is not the problem. The last one I've posted is me wondering if my adjustment gets closer to removing the issue (which you _still_ haven't really clarified beyond "blinking" or "flashing" which could mean different things to different people. A quick video might really help us, unless my comment about "resizing the box" is a good description?)

Comment: I think this 'blinking' might simply be that on click of the buttons clearStoryContainer() hides and empties the #story-container before fetching the new content.

Comment: @Moob my thoughts exactly. And visually I'd say it manifests itself more as the outer container div resizing itself to adjust to the size of the content within it, which is entirely natural (unless a fixed size is set for that container).

Comment: @PatrikQvarnström https://jsfiddle.net/0uarqLfk/3/ - at a guess, this is what you wanted? Please confirm, and I will post a proper answer.

Comment: `The issue is still there`...in that case please clarify what you really want to happen. If you load content into a div, it's inevitable that the size of the div will change based on the amount of content. That is the only visual change happening in my [last demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0uarqLfk/3/). It doesn't blink or flash, or momentarily disappear. It simply changes size. The only way to avoid that is to have a fixed-size div, but then you run the risk of the content overflowing and needing scrollbars. Would that be preferable?

Comment: `It looks like the buttons "jumps"`...I don't see anything like that in my last demo, sorry. They do move from one place to another it's true, but that is just to make space for the story content. Like I said, the whole outer div (with the white background) must resize itself for that. And because you have that container centered, the rest of the contents will also move so that the whole thing remains centred. If you don't want that, fix the size and/or don't centre it. You must decide what you want _instead_, as I said earlier.

Comment: ` even if I remove the CSS styling completely, the buttons is still appearing like if they're moving around` ... I can't reproduce that. It works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/kaLc7ywo/ . I would guess that something else is going on in your page which isn't shown in your question, or that you haven't actually removed all the CSS, - or perhaps that you need a new monitor, or new glasses ;-)

Comment: `When you're testing the code on that website ADyson, you can't actually display a story`....have you actually tried pressing the buttons? They display some data. It's not your story data, but it _is_ some data which fills the space. Enter a number and press the button, it will download and display data. If you've been viewing those demos without actually interacting with them, then it's perhaps no wonder you haven't grasped my point yet. Go back through all of them and try actually using them.

Comment: In your demo at https://jsfiddle.net/u6ymhowd/ the only "jumping" I observe is what I've already explained more than once before - the container box moves around and resizes to accomodate the downloaded text (or an error message), causing the buttons to move. But that just happens immediately after the button is pressed. Nothing else happens after that, until you either clear the text or you try to download another story. And it's unclear exactly what "starting to behave weird" means. Perhaps you can do a little video screengrab and post it somewhere so we can see what you really mean.

Comment: Maybe something like this would work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/au56p34t/1/

Comment: `is it possible to make the container smaller in width and have it in the center of the screen`...like this you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/ynp96kbu/

Comment: Just change x to y on the overflow, and width to height: https://jsfiddle.net/ynp96kbu/1/

Comment: Glad that helped. I wrote up our discussion into a proper answer, below, with the live demo embedded in it.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. Don't post answers inside the question! Either post your own answer below, or vote/accept existing answers which have helped you to solve the problem. Refer to [answer] and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). See also the [tour] if you need a reminder on how Stackoverflow's question and answer structure operates. Thanks!

Comment: Oh ok, so to get help with my current issue I'll have to ask another question?

Comment: It seems the issue you asked about in this post is resolved, hence why I wrote an answer to cover it. If you agree, you should mark it as accepted, and consider if it merits an upvote or not. Then yes, if you have a new and different problem, it should be the subject of a new question, which contains just a [mre] of that specific problem. (Otherwise, if you keep changing the issue, it makes the previous comments and answers far less meaningful for other readers, and can also lead to extremely long and confusing posts)

Comment: P.S. In my demo, the Clear button is still aligned correctly as far as I can see. So maybe you did something different in the version you applied in your page. You should analyse the differences closely to help spot the issue.

Comment: Here's a screenshot how it looks for me https://imageupload.io/4quysz6z76jhBAt I feel like the "Clear" button is a bit more to the left.

Comment: Examine it using your browser's developer tools and check its exact position, size etc. compared to the others. Then you'll know, rather than just feeling it. But yeah it does look a bit different. And as I said, do a detailed comparison of your CSS and mine. If you're still stuck after that, ask a new question with relevant details. In the meantime, consider marking this one as resolved by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from that fact that the main area of the page with the white background resizes according to its contents - so it expands when you display a story, contracts when you clear it again, and may resize larger or smaller when you change from one story to another.

This is because it doesn't have a fixed height or width, and is centred vertically and horizontally in the page, so it has to adjust its position, and the position of things within it, to maintain that centreing when it changes size. Also there is JS code which shows and hides the content area and changes margins etc, which is not helping either.

From the discussion it seems you would like to overcome this by removing the vertical centreing, but imposing a max height and a scrollbar on the vertical axis to keep the content area to a fixed size.

This demo (which is just using some random endpoint data) shows how it can be achieved with CSS:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var totalStories = 3;
  var currentStory = null;
  var storyContainer = document.getElementById('story-container');

  function clearStoryContainer() {
    if (storyContainer) {
      storyContainer.style.display = 'none';
      var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
      if (generatedTextElement) {
        generatedTextElement.innerHTML = '';
      }
      var contentWrapper = document.getElementById('content-wrapper');
      if (contentWrapper) {
        //contentWrapper.style.marginTop = '0';
      }
      currentStory = null;
    }
  }

  function fetchStory(storyNumber) {
   var stories = [
     "6525421912a5d3765989cff3",
     "6525469d54105e766fc05f92",
     "652546bd12a5d3765989d1a7"
   ];
    //clearStoryContainer();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/' + stories[storyNumber-1], true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        if (storyContainer) {
          storyContainer.style.display = 'block';
          var generatedText = xhr.responseText;
          var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
          if (generatedTextElement) {
            generatedTextElement.innerHTML = parseAndStyleTitles(generatedText);
          } else {
            console.log('Generated text element not found.');
          }
          var contentWrapper = document.getElementById('content-wrapper');
          if (contentWrapper) {
            //contentWrapper.style.marginTop = '60px';
          } else {
            console.log('Content wrapper element not found.');
          }
          currentStory = storyNumber;
        } else {
          console.log('Story container element not found.');
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Error fetching story. Status code: ' + xhr.status);
        clearStoryContainer();
        displayErrorMessage('Error fetching story.');
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      console.log('Network error while fetching story.');
      clearStoryContainer();
      displayErrorMessage('Network error while fetching story.');
    };
    xhr.send();
  }

  function displayErrorMessage(errorMessage) {
    if (storyContainer) {
      storyContainer.style.display = 'block';
    }
    var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
    if (generatedTextElement) {
      generatedTextElement.innerHTML = errorMessage;
    }
    var contentWrapper = document.getElementById('content-wrapper');
    if (contentWrapper) {
      //contentWrapper.style.marginTop = '60px';
    }
    currentStory = null;
  }

  function parseAndStyleTitles(text) {
    return text.replace(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g, function(match, title) {
      return '<span>' + title + '</span>';
    });
  }

  document.getElementById('get').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var storyNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('story-number').value);

    if (!isNaN(storyNumber) && storyNumber >= 1 && storyNumber <= totalStories) {
      fetchStory(storyNumber);
    } else {
      displayErrorMessage('Please enter a valid number between 1 and ' + totalStories + '.');
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('getRandom').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var randomStoryNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalStories) + 1;
    fetchStory(randomStoryNumber);
  });

  document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
    clearStoryContainer();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #ff6600;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#content-wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#story-number {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#get-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#get,
#getRandom,
#clear {
  background-color: #ff6600;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline: none;
  /* Remove focus outline */
}

#story-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

#generated-text {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}

#generated-text span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#clear {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

@media (min-width: 601px) {
  #content-wrapper {
/*    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 40vh;*/
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {

  #get,
  #clear {
    font-size: 10px !important;
    padding: 20px 20px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
    <header>
      <h1>Stories</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="get-container">
          <input type="text" id="story-number" placeholder="Enter story number">
          <button id="get" type="button">Get Story</button>
          <button id="getRandom" type="button">Random Story</button>
        </div>
        <div id="story-container">
          <!-- Story content will be displayed here -->
          <div id="generated-text"></div>
          <button id="clear">Clear</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```